# How do I get yesterday's time in milliseconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, milliseconds

I'm running into a wall.  I want to get yesterday's time in milliseconds.  I thought the below would do the job

```
irb(main):001:0> yday = 1.day.ago
=> Tue, 03 Apr 2018 20:35:24 UTC +00:00
irb(main):002:0> yday.strftime('%Q').to_f
=> 0.0
```

but as you can see I'm getting a "0.0" for yesterday's time.  How can I correct what I have to accurately get the time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

```
(DateTime.now-1.day).strftime('%Q')
```

Or:

```
yday = 1.day.ago
yday.to_datetime.strftime('%Q')
```

Why you need `to_datetime`? Well, `1.day.ago` is ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone which does not have `%Q` format ([documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)) when `strftime` for DateTime does ([documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime))